# Хранение и передача объектов класса c++

Tags: c++

Пишу либу для создания дискорд ботов.
У меня есть 2 основных класса, это Gateway и http.
В первом классе "общаюсь" с сервером на базе websocket протокола, т. е. при происхождении каких-либо событий сервер мне отправляет информацию об этом событии (например, юзер пишет сообщение - сервер мне отсылает тип события, текст сообщения, автора и др).

Во втором классе уже отправляю http запросы для выполнения различных действий (например, отправление или удаление сообщений).
Оба класса требуют токен для авторизации, поэтому решил создать класс Connection, который будет объединять оба этих класса, т. е. я единожды создаю в main объекты этих классов.

После этого я замораживаю main поток (чтобы не завершилась работа программы), а уже в классе Gateway создаются отдельные потоки, пингующие сервер или обрабатывающие события.

Класс http же мне нужен, например, уже после прохождения какого-то события или в другой необходимый момент.

Соответственно класс Gateway мне нужно создать только один раз и далее уже он самостоятельно будет выполнять различные операции по обработке событий, слежением за состоянием подключения, переподключением и т. д.

С классом http аналогично, создаю один раз и далее уже публичными методами отправляю ассинхронно запросы.

По моей задумке класс http будет членом других классов. Поэтому мне нужно как-то передать объект этого классу другому классу без его повторного создания. Собственно вопрос, как это лучше сделать?

К примеру, создаю новый класс Message. У этого класса есть метод send, который будет отправлять сообщение в канал. Для отправки мне нужен объект класса  http, как мне его получить? Создавать класс Connection глобально и получать через геттер-метод?

Наверное, не самый лучший вариант.

Где-то хранить адрес объекта http? Опять же, глобально. Наследование? По-моему, не очень подходит. Есть ли какой-то более разумный вариант? Желательно с примерами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо объект http передавать во все классы, нужно стараться не смешивать сущности, кроме, конечно случаев композиции, но это вопрос творческий.

В данном случае рекомендую использовать шаблон проектирования Observer (краеугольный камень библиотек язка Java).

Смысл его в том, что есть объекты-поставщики информации, а есть слушатели, потребители.

Объекты, создающие сообщения, это поставщики:

```
// Некий контейнер для сообщений
class MessagePayload...

// Очень важный интерфейс
class MessageProducerListener {
public:
    virtual void messageCreated(const MessagePayload& message) =0;
}

// Класс-поставщик создатель и поставщик сообщений
class MessageProducer {
    // Метод регистрации слушателя
    void setListener(MessageProducerListener* listener) {
        this._listener = listener;
    }
    void send() {
        // Сообщение готов?
        // Слушатель готов?
        if(_listener)
            // Передаем сообщение слушателю, он знает что с ним делать
            _listener->messageCreated(this->_message)
    }    
private:
    // Носитель сообщения, может любой сущностью
    MessagePayload _message;
}
```

Слушатели данного объекта, должны быть типа MessageProducerListener. Это могут быть как ваши классы http и Gateway, так и некий другой класс, который их объединяет (композирует, или агрегирует). Пусть это будет ваш класс Connection:

```
class Connection : public MessageBuilderListener {
public:
    void messageCreated(const MessagePayload& message) override {

        _http.send(message);
        _gateway.send(message)
        // Или как-то по-другому
    }

private:
    http _http;
    Gateway _gateway;
}


Теперь main.cpp:
void main(...) {

    Connection c;

    MessageProducer producer1;
    producer1.setListener(&c)

    MessageProducer producer2;
    producer2.setListener(&c)

    ...

    MessageProducer producerN;
    producerN.setListener(&c)

}
```

Как видите объект Connection создан в одном экземпляре, внутри него http и Gateway тоже каждый в одном экземпляре. И самое главное все развязано и не мешает друг другу